# GLSL Procedural Texture

Tags: algorithm, opengl, glsl, textures, fragment-shader

can someone help me, i need to make some procedural textures in shader program GLSL, i have one of them but i need all and i don't know how to do them.

http://puu.sh/plXYT/4c279d6de3.png - This can be useful

This is what i have:

```
    #version 140

in vec2 texCoord; 

out vec4 fColor; 


    void main()
    {
        const float size = 10.0; 

        fColor = vec4(mod(floor(size * texCoord.t) + floor(size * texCoord.s), 2.0) + (mod(floor(size * texCoord.s),2.0) * mix(  vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0) , ( vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0) ), (fract(size * texCoord.s) + fract(size * texCoord.t))/2.0 )));

    }
```

And this is what i need to do
http://puu.sh/plSwB/9ae1adee13.png

Comment: It's not my code so i dont understand it well

Comment: can you execute it and upload a screenshot?

Comment: http://puu.sh/plV0Q/4dff0589e0.png

Comment: ok. and which one of the other two do you need

Comment: I need both of them

Comment: @willywonkadailyblah can you do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for the second one:

```
const float num = 6.0;
const float wid = 0.1;
const vec4 c_back = vec4(0.55, 0.35, 0.0, 1.0);
const vec4 c_edge = vec4(0.28, 0.48, 0.05, 1.0);
const vec4 c_beam = vec4(0.19, 0.77, 0.06, 1.0);

float y = mod(texcoord.t, 1.0 / (num - 1.0)) * (num - 1.0);
float dy = (y < 0.5) ? y : 1.0 - y;
fColor = (dy > wid) ? c_back : mix(c_beam, c_edge, dy / wid);

float x = mod(texcoord.s, 1.0 / (num - 1.0)) * (num - 1.0);
float dx = (x < 0.5) ? x : 1.0 - x;
if (dx <= wid) fColor = mix(c_beam, c_edge, dx / wid);
```

And for the third:

```
const float num = 3.5;
const float gap = 0.03;
const vec4 c_insd = vec4(0.05, 0.30, 0.57, 1.0);
const vec4 c_back = vec4(0.75, 0.73, 0.73, 1.0);

const float reg = 0.5 / num;
float rx = texcoord.s / reg,
      ry = texcoord.t / reg;
float x = fract(rx), 
      y = fract(ry);

if (x < gap || x > 1.0 - gap || y < gap || y > 1.0 - gap)
   fColor = c_back;
else
{
   if (mod(floor(rx) + floor(ry), 2.0) == 0.0)
      fColor = (y - x > 0.5 || x - y > 0.5) ? c_back : c_insd;
   else
      fColor = (y + x < 0.5 || x + y > 1.5) ? c_back : c_insd;
}
```

Comment: What target picture ?

Comment: @BartoszCieślar just as i thought. this should be it.

Comment: If you can i'll be grateful

Comment: @BartoszCieślar ok have a look. btw this looks like something off Doom lol

Comment: @BartoszCieślar no problem. fun problem for me too